# How to make manipulating all-white objects without a background easier in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, transparency

I'm sure it's a common frustration but I couldn't find an answer. I'm making white icons in Inkscape (with a transparent background) and I couldn't find a way to set up my document so that the screen's background is some other colour than white. Obviously white on white isn't easy to see!

I can obviously add a rectangle of any dark colour below my object and make sure to delete it when I export my icons, but it's quite tedious, and it causes me to accidentally select the background all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not perfect, but a usable work-around that I do:

1. While editing your icons, **give the *document* a non-white background color**. This setting is in "File" > "Document Properties" (Remember to set the alpha to opaque)
2. Then before you're done, go back to the document background and set the alpha to be fully transparent

Answer (score 5):

Another option, also not perfect:

Instead of setting the document properties to have a non-white background colour, you could add a coloured rectangle to a second layer underneath your drawing. This allows the background to be quickly switched between white and your chosen colour by setting the layer visibility.